# How do I delete a container-bound script when a Google Sheet is pointing to multiple?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been put in charge to automate several Google Sheets for different teams throughout our organization.
It started out with 1 main template. Easy enough.
That template is copied each time a new project comes in.

Eventually a second template was born off of the original (the original is still used as well though)
Some changes were made to the UI of the sheet and I added additional automation based off of the new columns. All seemed well.

As of last week, when I go to the Script Editor of a sheet I get this window:

[image]

Let's say I select the first option. If I edit it and test the code, it doesn't work as expected because it's still pulling from the other 2 scripts!

I don't know when or how this happened.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage you script by going to: [Google Scripts](http://script.google.com/)

Comment: I'm aware of that @RemcoE33.
However when I pull up the scripts and go into the details of it, it shows that it's paired to whichever container. And multiple scripts are bound to 1 container. 
I can't have that. Which is the question that I asked. How can I get rid of them and only have the 1 script bound to the container?

Comment: You can just delete them by clicking on the 3 little dots. It won't delete the container, just the script project on that 'container'

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I guess I'll have to wait until EOD in case some people are trying to use one of the variants of the templates.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: one more question @RemcoE33.
In your opinion what would best practice be?
Should I delete all 3 scripts, remake them as standalone scripts and name them, and then paste the code back into each sheet?
Trying to think of what would work best.

Comment: @Micheal if you want to start fresh I would invest the time to to indeed what you suggested